# Datepicker conversion issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, date

I'm new to all this and I'm a hard time trying to do what appears to be a simple thing. This is what I'm trying to do. I'm using jquery datapicker to create two dates. A beginning date (beginningdate) and an end date (enddate). I need to use these dates for the following things:

1. Use the 2 dates in a where statement in a mySQL query.
2. Calculate the difference between the dates and use them in the same where statement in the mySQL query.
3. Use the mySQL statement to populate a chart using AMCharts.
4. Use the same page to draw that chart.

So basically, I'm trying to input the two dates and use those two dates to populate a chart without using two pages to do it. So this is what I have done so far.

1. Created a php page called mealplanner.php
2. Created a form on this page and added the two dates fields
3. After posting, the two dates work in the where statement (number 1 above) using

   ```
   where m.date >= ('" . $_POST['beginningdate'] . "')
   and m.date <= ('" . $_POST['enddate'] . "')
   ```
4. The chart populates on the same mealplanner.php page since I am refreshing the page after post (number 3 and 4).
5. After or during the posting, I need to calculate the difference between the 2 dates and use that number in a php variable named $diffdate. This is where I run into issues. I can manually hard code a javascript variable

   ```
   var diffdate = 9;
   ```

I can then pass that variable to php during post using

```
    window.location.href = "?p=mealplanner&diffdate=" + diffdate;
```

and use

```
    $diffdate = $_GET["diffdate"];
```

in my php section to use the variable in my mySQL statement but I obviously can't use a hard coded variable and need to calculate the two dates. this is my html form

```
    <form id="changedate" action="?p=mealplanner" method="post">
    <p>Beginning Date: <br /><input type="text" id="BeginningDate" name="beginningdate"></p>        
<br />
<p>End Date: <br /><input type="text" id="EndDate" name="enddate"></p>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Change Dates" onclick="calcdate();" />
<br />
</form>
```

and this is how I'm converting the jquery element into a variable

```
    var BeginningDate = document.getElementById("BeginningDate").value;
    var EndDate = document.getElementById("EndDate").value;
```

The problem is that the date is now a string and I can't seem to convert it to a date. I would think that using

```
    var newdate = new Date('BeginningDate');
```

Would work but it doesn't, I even tried double quoting it. I have tried this:

```
     var dateArr=BeginningDate.split("/");
     var date=new BeginningDate( parseInt(dateArr[0], 10),
               parseInt(dateArr[1], 10)-1,
               parseInt(dateArr[2], 10),
               parseInt(dateArr[3], 10);

    alert(date);
```

It simply doesn't see the sting as a date. I also create and display default fields using today as the beginning date and today +7 and the end date. Of course, if I change the dates, the post refresh puts the default back so I need a way to keep the new dates displaying on the after post page. I would assume a issset will be the way to do it but I haven't tried it yet and am looking for suggestions on how to do that as welll. I hope this makes sense and thanks in advance. Here is my datepicker functions if you need that as well.

```
    $(function() {  
$( "#BeginningDate" ).datepicker();
$( "#BeginningDate" ).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
$( "#BeginningDate" ).datepicker('option', {dateFormat: 'yy/mm/d'});
      });

$(function() {
$( "#EndDate" ).datepicker();
$( "#EndDate" ).datepicker("setDate", "+7");
$( "#EndDate" ).datepicker('option', {dateFormat: 'yy/mm/d'});
 });
```

Comment: You can use `$("#xxxDate").datepicker("getDate")` to get the date that was chosen, you don't need to parse the date yourself. Datepicker also has `$.datepicker.parseDate()`, which takes a format string.

Comment: Not sure where that line would go.

Comment: It goes in place of your `var date = new BeginningDate(...)`.

Comment: Sorry still lost. the only place I have var date = new BeginningDate(..) is the parse area. I'm not sure how I would calculate the dates after that and convert it to a php variable.

Comment: I'm saying that you don't need to parse the dates yourself, datepicker will do it for you.

Comment: BTW, I assume `new BeginningDate` was a copying error, it's really `new Date`.

Comment: I get that, so how do I calculate the dates, then convert it to a php variable so the mySql script can read it using the datepicker dates?

Comment: I would just use `dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'` in the datepicker. Then the form field will contain the date in the proper format for sending to MySQL.

Comment: I can't send it directly to mySQL because the datepicker is only the date, not the difference between the 2 dates. I need to calculate the difference, then send it to mySQL as a php variable. I got the datepicker dates working in the script, I need the difference calculated, then sent to mySQL.

Comment: `diff = ($("#EndDate").datepicker("getDate").getTime() - $("#BeginningDate").datepicker("getDate").getTime())/86400000;`

Comment: Got it, it worked. Thanks. Any idea on how to populate the new dates when it refreshes instead of reverting back to the original default dates?